# Can email from web-based email service be tracked to my location?

Tags: gmail, geolocation, ip-addresses, aol-mail

I'm planning to send an email to someone and I have reasons to not want him to be able to find my location.

If I send an email, let's say: from my Hotmail to his Gmail or AOL account, will he be able to track me down?

How can I send him something without him finding what state, city, etc. that I'm from?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if hotmail updated their functionality, but earlier Hotmail & AOL used to include sender's IP address **X-Originating-IP** in the email header. Same is applicable for Yahoo as well.

However, if you send through GMAIL, ip address will not be included in the email if you send it through web ui. I remember that they have updated so that even desktop mail clients also include this(still to be verified). However there are other information that can be used to guess location. For example, sender's timezone will be included in gmail.

If IP address is available, you can't always guarantee that a precise location may be found, but there is certain chance depending on your connection.

Source:
http://www.wikihow.com/Trace-an-Email
http://aruljohn.com/info/howtofindipaddress/#hotmail
http://www.labnol.org/internet/find-location-of-gmail-sender/21098/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what they include in the email's headers. E.g. [X-Originating-IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Originating-IP):

> In 1999 Hotmail included an X-Originating-IP email header field that
>   shows the IP address of the sender. As of December 2012, Hotmail
>   removed this header field, replacing it with X-EIP (meaning encoded
>   IP) with the stated goal of protecting users' privacy.

Some services such as [ip-address](http://www.ip-address.org/tracker/trace-email.php#email_headers) analyze the email's headers to get the sender's IP address if available:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use a VPN service - like the free online [VPN Tunnel](https://www.vpntunnel.com/), your IP will never be revealed.